# Best Ef core strategy to run migrations for a lot of databases?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, singleton, entity-framework-migrations, multi-tenant

I am using **Ef Core** in a **multi tenant** database design project. To get the right connection string in every request I have a database to store connections and I am using a **Singleton** to cache the connections(doing this, if the connection is in the dictionary of singleton, it isn't necessary to get the connection again in database).

To run the migrations, I created a program to run the migrations in each database and it is working. The problem is that every time I change anything on the schema, and I need to deploy, I need to run this program but are getting slower depending on the amount of databases. I wonder how this would be if we have something like 200, 300 databases.

I am thinking about running the migrations, each time that I try to get a connection in my singleton connection dictionary and don't get it. I am thinking that doing this, the singleton would "restart" when I deploy the application and in the first time that an user try to execute any request, the database would be upgraded. I am wondering if this could execute more times than I am expecting.

What do you think? Do you know a better strategy?

Thank you